# Faced "Not in outer par mode" error when I want to add table into my CV

Tags: tables, errors, cv

Well, I had just generated a table from www.tablesgenerator.com and paste the whole code into my document, but suddenly I faced "Not in outer par mode" error.
Also, I've added the relevant package to my document preamble (usepackage{graphicx}).

I've searched a lot but couldn't find the suitable solution for it.

You can find my project in a link below. Also, you are able to make any changes:

https://www.overleaf.com/10878247fnsprqcsmfmy

You can find a table codes from line 153 to 168.

Here are the related codes:
    \section{Education}

```
\runsubsection{Bachelor of Engineer in Software Engineer}
\descript{ Department of Engineer + Azad University of Tehran-north}

\location{Grad June 2017 | IRAN, Tehran}
\location{Project:  Implementation of e-commerce Web Application}
\location{Advisor:  Dr.K.Layeghi}
\location{Last Year GPA:    3.79 or (18.60)}
\location{Last 2 Years GPA: 3.18 or (16.74)}
\descript{BE Project Summary}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightitemize}
\item Implementation of e-commerce Web Application
\end{tightitemize}
\descript{Modules Included}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Introduction to Computers and Programming & A  & Algorithms Design                                      
& A  \\
Advanced Programing                       & A+ & Compiler Design and         
Implementation & A+ \\
Internet Engineering                      & A  & User Interface Design              
& A  \\
Computer Networks                         & A  & Digital Logic Design               
& A+ \\
Databases Lab                             & A  & Technical Presentation             
& A  \\
Computer Lab                              & A+ & Software Projects Managment        
& A+ \\
Analytics and Statistics                  & A+ & Entrepeneurship                    
& A+
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\sectionspace % Some whitespace after the section
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle and sorry because I'm not very familiar. I added the related codes to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the lines

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
```

and the closing

```
}
\end{table}
```

You do not want this table to float to another part of the document (and it is not allowed to float from inside the `minipage` hence the error) so you do not want `\begin{table}` and you almost never want to put tables in `\resizebox` which by design produces font sizes inconsistent with the rest of the document.